# add latex type equation in word (.docx) using Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am trying to create an automated (.docx) MS Word file using Apache POI. The input of the Java program contains text, images and LaTeX style equations (embedded in $ $ or [  ]).

My problem is How can I add this LaTeX style equation in Word so that when the .docx file get edited in MS Word it recognizes the equation as MS Word style equation (OMML type)

**NOTE:** I think the way should be converting LaTeX equation into MathML. if so, then how can I add the MathML into .docx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft provides XSLT stylesheets for transforming OMML to MathML (`OMML2MML.XSL`) as well as for transforming MathML to OMML (`MML2OMML.XSL`) using `XSLT`.

If you have installed `Microsoft Office`, you will find those files in the Office program directory. In my system:

[image]

Using this we can transform MathML to OMML using XSLT.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMathPara;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTR;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;

/*
needs the full ooxml-schemas-*.jar or poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025
*/

public class CreateWordFormulaFromMathML {

 static File stylesheet = new File("MML2OMML.XSL");
 static TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 static StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet); 

 static CTOMath getOMML(String mathML) throws Exception {
  Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);

  StringReader stringreader = new StringReader(mathML);
  StreamSource source = new StreamSource(stringreader);

  StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringwriter);
  transformer.transform(source, result);

  String ooML = stringwriter.toString();
  stringwriter.close();

  CTOMathPara ctOMathPara = CTOMathPara.Factory.parse(ooML);
  CTOMath ctOMath = ctOMathPara.getOMathArray(0);

  //for making this to work with Office 2007 Word also, special font settings are necessary
  XmlCursor xmlcursor = ctOMath.newCursor();
  while (xmlcursor.hasNextToken()) {
   XmlCursor.TokenType tokentype = xmlcursor.toNextToken();
   if (tokentype.isStart()) {
    if (xmlcursor.getObject() instanceof CTR) {
     CTR cTR = (CTR)xmlcursor.getObject();
     cTR.addNewRPr2().addNewRFonts().setAscii("Cambria Math");
     cTR.getRPr2().getRFonts().setHAnsi("Cambria Math"); // up to apache poi 4.1.2
     //cTR.getRPr2().getRFontsArray(0).setHAnsi("Cambria Math"); // since apache poi 5.0.0
    }
   }
  }

  return ctOMath;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The Pythagorean theorem: ");

  String mathML = 
    "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\">" 
   +"<mrow>"
   +"<msup><mi>a</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>+</mo><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>=</mo><msup><mi>c</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>"
   +"</mrow>"
   +"</math>";

  CTOMath ctOMath = getOMML(mathML);
System.out.println(ctOMath);

  CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
  ctp.setOMathArray(new CTOMath[]{ctOMath});

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The Quadratic Formula: ");

  mathML = 
    "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\">"
   +"<mrow>" 
   +"<mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo><mfrac><mrow><mrow><mo>-</mo><mi>b</mi></mrow><mo>±</mo><msqrt><mrow><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>4</mn><mo>⁢</mo><mi>a</mi><mo>⁢</mo><mi>c</mi></mrow></mrow></msqrt></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>⁢</mo><mi>a</mi></mrow></mfrac>"
   +"</mrow>"
   +"</math>";

  ctOMath = getOMML(mathML);
System.out.println(ctOMath);

  ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
  ctp.setOMathArray(new CTOMath[]{ctOMath});
  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordFormulaFromMathML.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Note that this code needs the full `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` or `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar` as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025.

---

There are of course Java libraries available for converting LaTeX to MathML. For example: http://www.fmath.info/java/download.jsp.

Downloaded: `fmath-mathml-java-test-project-b1124.zip` and having `/lib/fmath-mathml-java.jar` and `/lib/jdom-2.0.6.jar` in class-path, the following works:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMathPara;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTR;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;

/*
needs the full ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025
*/

public class CreateWordFormulaFromLaTeX {

 static File stylesheet = new File("MML2OMML.XSL");
 static TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 static StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet); 

 static CTOMath getOMML(String mathML) throws Exception {
  Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);

  StringReader stringreader = new StringReader(mathML);
  StreamSource source = new StreamSource(stringreader);

  StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringwriter);
  transformer.transform(source, result);

  String ooML = stringwriter.toString();
  stringwriter.close();

  CTOMathPara ctOMathPara = CTOMathPara.Factory.parse(ooML);
  CTOMath ctOMath = ctOMathPara.getOMathArray(0);

  //for making this to work with Office 2007 Word also, special font settings are necessary
  XmlCursor xmlcursor = ctOMath.newCursor();
  while (xmlcursor.hasNextToken()) {
   XmlCursor.TokenType tokentype = xmlcursor.toNextToken();
   if (tokentype.isStart()) {
    if (xmlcursor.getObject() instanceof CTR) {
     CTR cTR = (CTR)xmlcursor.getObject();
     cTR.addNewRPr2().addNewRFonts().setAscii("Cambria Math");
     cTR.getRPr2().getRFonts().setHAnsi("Cambria Math");
    }
   }
  }

  return ctOMath;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The Pythagorean theorem: ");

  String latex = "$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$";

  String mathML = fmath.conversion.ConvertFromLatexToMathML.convertToMathML(latex);
  mathML = mathML.replaceFirst("<math ", "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\" ");
System.out.println(mathML);

  CTOMath ctOMath = getOMML(mathML);
System.out.println(ctOMath);

  CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
  ctp.setOMathArray(new CTOMath[]{ctOMath});


  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The Quadratic Formula: ");

  latex = "$x=\\frac{-b\\pm\\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$";

  mathML = fmath.conversion.ConvertFromLatexToMathML.convertToMathML(latex);
  mathML = mathML.replaceFirst("<math ", "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\" ");
  mathML = mathML.replaceAll("&plusmn;", "±");
System.out.println(mathML);

  ctOMath = getOMML(mathML);
System.out.println(ctOMath);

  ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
  ctp.setOMathArray(new CTOMath[]{ctOMath});

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordFormulaFromLaTeX.docx"));
  document.close();

 }
}
```

But each transforming includes possible errors. So LaTeX -> MathML -> OMML will be much more error prone than only MathML -> OMML.

In this case the `fmath.conversion.ConvertFromLatexToMathML.convertToMathML` results in `Math` `XML` without name space. But since `XSLT` needs this, it must be added manually.

And `fmath.conversion.ConvertFromLatexToMathML.convertToMathML` uses `HTML` entities which `MML2OMML.XSL` does not knows. So in the example "±" must be replaced with "±".

---

Maybe [SnuggleTeX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/) will be the better library?

Downloaded it and having `snuggletex-core-1.2.2.jar` in class-path, the following code changings in my last example works:

```
...
  String latex = "$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$";

  uk.ac.ed.ph.snuggletex.SnuggleEngine engine = new uk.ac.ed.ph.snuggletex.SnuggleEngine();
  uk.ac.ed.ph.snuggletex.SnuggleSession session = engine.createSession();
  uk.ac.ed.ph.snuggletex.SnuggleInput input = new uk.ac.ed.ph.snuggletex.SnuggleInput(latex);
  session.parseInput(input);
  String mathML = session.buildXMLString();
System.out.println(mathML);

/*
  String mathML = fmath.conversion.ConvertFromLatexToMathML.convertToMathML(latex);
  mathML = mathML.replaceFirst("<math ", "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\" ");
System.out.println(mathML);
*/

  CTOMath ctOMath = getOMML(mathML);
System.out.println(ctOMath);

...

  latex = "$x=\\frac{-b\\pm\\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$";

  engine = new uk.ac.ed.ph.snuggletex.SnuggleEngine();
  session = engine.createSession();
  input = new uk.ac.ed.ph.snuggletex.SnuggleInput(latex);
  session.parseInput(input);
  mathML = session.buildXMLString();
System.out.println(mathML);

/*
  mathML = fmath.conversion.ConvertFromLatexToMathML.convertToMathML(latex);
  mathML = mathML.replaceFirst("<math ", "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\" ");
  mathML = mathML.replaceAll("&plusmn;", "±");
System.out.println(mathML);
*/

  ctOMath = getOMML(mathML);
System.out.println(ctOMath);
...
```

There no manually interventions are necessary. At least not using the given LaTeX examples.

Comment: Thank You! Appears to be working perfectly fine. is there any way to convert LaTeX style equation to MathML through java?

Comment: For making this to work with Office 2007 Word also, special font settings are necessary, see my supplements in code. And to your question about any way to convert LaTeX style equation to MathML through java: What was the result of your researches about this? Surely there are any ways but each transforming includes possible errors. So LaTeX -> MathML -> OMML will be much more error prone than only MathML -> OMML. So do the trial/error yourself.

Comment: @ Axel Richter providing Input in Latex style is much easier. Also, I only found [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) which have the capability to convert Latex to MathML. But it is a web application and not java.

Comment: @ashwin bande: There are of course Java libraries available for converting LaTeX to MathML. I currently found [SnuggleTeX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/) as the best. See my supplements. But you have to test this your  own.

Comment: the [SnuggleTex](https://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/) is the perfect solution. even better than fmath. Thanks Again!

Comment: Is there any way to add multiple equations and text in the same line? because I tried to do it but it is not working.

Comment: Would you please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644488/how-to-add-multiple-equations-inline-with-text-in-apache-poi-word) question regarding to it?