# How to add multiple equations inline with text in Apache POI Word?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, mathml

I am converting text with latex style equation into MS word document using Apache POI. with some help, I was able to implement it successfully but if the line has more than one equation then it produces an incorrect result.

following is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMathPara;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import uk.ac.ed.ph.snuggletex.SnuggleInput;
import uk.ac.ed.ph.snuggletex.SnuggleEngine;
import uk.ac.ed.ph.snuggletex.SnuggleSession;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CreateWordFormulaFromMathML {

 static File stylesheet = new File("MML2OMML.XSL");
 static TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 static StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet); 

 static CTOMath getOMML(String mathML) throws Exception {
  Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);

  StringReader stringreader = new StringReader(mathML);
  StreamSource source = new StreamSource(stringreader);

  StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringwriter);
  transformer.transform(source, result);

  String ooML = stringwriter.toString();
  stringwriter.close();

  CTOMath ctOMath = CTOMath.Factory.parse(ooML);
  return ctOMath.getOMathArray(0);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  String mstr = "The expression is as: $ax^2 + bx = c$ is easier to understand than $$ax^2 + \\frac{\\sin^{-1}\\theta}{\\cot{-1}} \\times y_1$$ or anything in \\[ ay^2 + b_2 \\theta\\]";

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
 // run.setText("");

  SnuggleEngine engine = new SnuggleEngine();
  SnuggleSession session = engine.createSession();

  SnuggleInput input = new SnuggleInput(mstr);
  session.parseInput(input);

  String mathML = session.buildXMLString();
  System.out.println("Input " + input.getString() + " was converted to:\n" + mathML + "\n\n");


for(String s : mathML.split("\\s+(?=<math)|(?<=</math>)\\s+")){

if (s.startsWith("<math"))
{
    CTOMath ctOMath = getOMML(s);
    System.out.println(s);

    CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
    ctp.setOMathArray(new CTOMath[]{ctOMath});        
}
else
{
    run.setText(s + " ");
    System.out.println(s);
}
}

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordFormulaFromMathML.docx"));
  document.close();

 }
}
```

This producing a document with

The expression is as: is easier to understand than or anything in ay^2+b_2 \theta

Note : (ay^2+b_2 \theta) is correctly in word equation format.

What I need is inline text with multipal equations in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to approach solving tasks for creating `Office OpenXML` files such as `*.docx`?

`Office OpenXML` files such as `*.docx` are siply `ZIP` archives. We can unzip them and have a look into the internals. In `*.docx` we find `/word/document.xml` and there we find `XML` which describes the document structure. For paragraphs having formula inline we find something like:

```
<w:p>
 <w:r>
  <w:t>text</w:t>
 </w:r>
 <m:oMath>... </m:oMath>
 <w:r>
  <w:t>text</w:t>
 </w:r>
 <m:oMath>... </m:oMath>
 ...
</w:p>
```

So we need multiple runs holding the text and between them multiple `<m:oMath>... </m:oMath>`.

Thats why the paragraph has a `OMathArray` `CTOMath[]`. And your code does overwriting this array with a new array  having **one** `CTOMath` **each** time a additional `CTOMath` was found. Instead an additional `CTOMath` needs to be added to the array, each time an additional `CTOMath` was found.

To know what we can do with `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP` paragraphs, we need a documentation for this. Best I have found is [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTP.java). There we find [CTP.addNewOMath()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTP.java#CTP.addNewOMath%28%29) and [CTP.setOMathArray(int, CTOMath)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTP.java#CTP.setOMathArray%28int%2Corg.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath%29).

So changing your code like:

```
  for(String s : mathML.split("\\s+(?=<math)|(?<=</math>)\\s+")){

   if (s.startsWith("<math")) {
    CTOMath ctOMath = getOMML(s);
    System.out.println(s);

    CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
    ctp.addNewOMath();
    ctp.setOMathArray(ctp.sizeOfOMathArray()-1, ctOMath);        
   }
   else {
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText(s + " ");
    System.out.println(s);
   }
  }
```

should work.